# NavigationExperimental is rendering all routes in the navigationstate on every transition

Tags: navigation, react-native

I've implemented NavigationExperimental. I'm on RN 0.35. I use a reducer based on Immutable Records, which leads to some PropType warnings when I feed it into NavigationCardStack. Other than the following issue, it seems to work ok.

The problem that I see is that all routes in the navigation routes structure are being rendered on each transition to a new route. Except when I pop a route, and remove an item from that list, I'm seeing rerenders for all the items. Is there any way where I can limit that?

I understand that for transition purposes we need to keep the previous scene, but other than that it doesn't make sense to me that everything in the list is rendered (I must be doing something wrong).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're using NavigationCardStack? Reading the source, yeah it seems to render all scenes you pass to it. You may want to try adding `shouldComponentUpdate` if there's a performance problem. Why exactly is it a problem if they re-render?

Comment: Some of these scenes are expensive to render, so when you spend cycles rendering things off-screen, it's a problem. I added a solution where I use the scene distance to determine whether a scene should be re-rendered.